# Amazon Windows EC2 Instance CPU Throttling - Unable to Connect Through RDP

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-ec2, windows-server

My AWS EC2 t3.large Windows instance CPU usage randomly reaches 100% (Viewed through AWS Monitoring). The application deployed on the instance should not even take it to an average of 5% yet this event has occurred. Furthermore, this occurred at low load times of the day which does not make much sense. At this usage, all my APIs stopped responding as well.

The problem is that I am unable to access my instance through RDP (or any other means) when the usage goes to a 100% because it becomes completely unresponsive. And so, I am unable to diagnose which processes/services are causing this. After around 1-2 hours, the usage rates return to normal e.g. 2%-7%.

[CPU usage temporary surge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lapMN.png)

[All resources monitoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC6kn.png)

I constantly tried to connect through RDP. The moment I was able to connect through RDP, the usage rates came back to normal and I could not deduce what caused the surge.

How can I diagnose what might be causing this? I am afraid that even if I run a scheduled/Cron script to log processes/services and CPU usage, it might not work at 100% usage times. For now, I am following [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/troubleshoot-high-cpu-in-iis-app-pool](https://Microsoft%27s%20guide)

Comment: StackOverflow is for Programming Q&A. You might receive a better response at: https://serverfault.com/